# validate a phone number field?

Tags: html, validation

i need to validate a phone number field in my form my conditions are numbers may be 8 digits or 10 digits other than that should be give an notice the way i try is like this is this ok ??

```
<input class="form-control" name="phone_no" id="phone_no" placeholder="Enter a Phone Number" type="tel"  title='Phone Number(Format:04xxxxxxx)' size="10" min="8" max="10" required>
```

or how use the patter attribute to achieve this??`pattern='\d{3}\d{4}\d{4}'`
like this i used but i need to check whether its between 8 and 10 less than 8 and more than 10 should give an error or notice!

Comment: You can use javascript to validate this

Comment: any example please????

Comment: I added simple example as a answer.please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a javascript function which will detect if the number is Australian Landline, or Australian Mobile, and format them accordingly.
It accepts +61 for landline and mobile, and requires Area Codes for landlines.

feel free to add to it if you think its missing functionality

```
    function validatePhoneNumber(phone_number){
        var formatted = "";
        //remove all non-digits
        phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\D/g,'');
        //if number starts with 61, replace 61 with 0
        if (phone_number.match(/^61/)){
              phone_number = "0"+phone_number.slice(2);
        }
        if (phone_number.match(/^04/)){
            if (phone_number.length === 10){
                var formatted = phone_number.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{3})/g,"$1 $2 $3");
            } else {
                alert('Invalid phone number');
            }
        } else if (phone_number.match(/^02|03|07|08/)){
            if (phone_number.length === 10) {
                var formatted = phone_number.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{4})/g,"($1) $2 $3");
            } else {
                alert('Invalid phone number');
            }
        } else if (phone_number.length === 8){
            alert('Please use Area Code for landline numbers');
        } else {

            alert('Invalid phone number');
        }
        //update
        $("#phone").val(formatted);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use followin javascript to validate text field length.

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("phone_no");

if(isNaN(textBox.value)){
  alert("Please inser a number as a phone number");
}
if(textBox.value.length < 8 || textBox.value.length > 10){
  alert("Enter text length between 8 to 10");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, using the pattern attribute is not so well supported (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp), so you should use javascript.  A regex for a phone number has already been discussed at length here: [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation).

Personally, I'd advise reading though the answer that suggests `.*` as a pattern.

Answer (score -1):

You can use pattern `'\d{8}\d?\d?'` or `\d{8}|\d{9}|\d{10}`.

Answer (score -2):

It worked for me

```
pattern="[0-9]{10}"
```